# How to drop/redefine inter-type declaration in AspectJ?

Tags: java, declaration, aspectj, aop

I use parser generator, which generates java classes representing syntax nodes of a programming language, and AspectJ aspects for adding semantics to these classes.
I have extended/changed the grammar of the language and I want to reuse aspects of the old grammar and modify/extend them to cope with changes of node classes.

For example, an old node class and its aspect:

```
class A {
  public T a1;
  public U a2;
  ...
}

aspect Accessors1 {
  public T A.getT() {return a1;}
  public U A.getU() {return a2;}
}
```

With grammar modification, the class A is change followingly:

```
class A {
  public T a1;
  public V a2;
  public U a3;
  ...
}
```

I would like to reuse the Accessors1 aspect and add another one:

```
aspect Accessors2 {
  public V A.getV() {return a2;} // new accessor for new field
  public U A.getU() {return a3;} // modification of old accessor
}
```

I tried this:

```
declare precedence: *2, *1;
```

But I still get this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from V to U` from the first aspect. Even though the Accessors1.getU() is not used, it is still type-checked, which causes compilation to fail.

Why is that so? How can I override the original `getU()` with the new one? Is there a way to tell AspectJ to ignore/drop the Accessors1.getU()?

Comment: are you parameterizing the class or are T, V, U real classes?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to use the following changes in second class:

```
class A {
  public T a1;
  public U a2;
  public V a3;
  ...
}
```

And the second aspect:

```
aspect Accessors2 {
  public V A.getV() {return a3;} // new accessor for new field
  public U A.getU() {return a2;} // modification of old accessor
}
```

Comment: That would be nice and easy solution to the problem, but as I mentioned, the classes are generated by parser generator.. and there is a LOT of them and hence a LOT of instances of the problem and of places to change...